# How do I get the first name and last name of a logged in user in Django?

Tags: python, django, view, models

I need to get the first name and last name of a user for a function in my views How do I do that? What is the syntax for it? I used request.user.email for the email, but I don't know see an option for a first name or last name. How do I go about doing this?

Should I import the model into the views and then use it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are multiple ways to get the information you require.

- `request.user.get_full_name()`, returns the first name and last name, separated by a space.
- `request.user.get_short_name()`, returns just the first name

You can also access the attributes directly, with `request.user.first_name` and `request.user.last_name`, but it is preferred to use the methods as the attributes may change in future versions.

The django user model has a rich set of methods, which you can read about in [the reference for the `auth` application](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/).

Answer (score 4):

You want the `first_name` and `last_name` attributes: `request.user.first_name` and `request.user.last_name`

Comment: What do you mean populated?

Comment: I mean if the user hasn't filled in their name in the signup form, or whatever you used to create them, then obviously that won't be there.

Comment: Yes, but in that case, won't that field be left null or blank or with an empty string?

Comment: You're right, that should be the case. Haven't tested but I assume that is correct. Edited the answer.